# Query ODataV4 connected service with LINQ - Get last record from table

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-nav, odata-v4

Im trying to query my OData webservice from a C# application.

When i do the following:

```
var SecurityDefs = from SD in nav.ICESecurityDefinition.Take(1) 
                   orderby SD.Entry_No descending 
                   select SD;
```

i get an exception because .top() and .orderby is not supposed to be used together.

I need to get the last record in the dataset and only the last.

The purpose is to get the last used entry number in a ledger and then continue creating new entries incrementing the found entry no.

I cant seem to find anything online that explains how to do this.

Its very important that the service only returns the last record from the feed since speed is paramount in this solution.

Comment: If you can change code in Nav, then I’d propose you to either make Entry No an autoincrement field (which I a default practice) or put some code into OnInsert trigger of the table to always create new entry number when inserting.

Comment: I am indeed able to change NAV. The reason i want the Entry No. of the last record is because i am going to insert a bunch of other records in subtables related to the "header" much like in the Sales Header Sales Line kind of way. In order to avoid fetching too many records from the webservice i wanted to just get the Header Entry No and then use this to populate the primary key of the underlying records before sending the records to NAV via OData.

Comment: Well I can understand that, but... First of al, If you have a subtables, then you can actually post them along with the header in one request. At least I’m sure you can do that for one subtable. Not sure if it is possible for “bunch” of them. In that case you can create key for header and lines in Nav, as suggested before and don’t bother with the key at all. And insert request will return you the key value anyway, so you can use it for the rest of the tables. Second, your current approach isn’t prone fore concurrency errors.

Comment: So if i send the header record before creating the sublines the service will return my entry no. since its the primary key to the c# app?

Comment: I can’t tell what you will get in C# but OData always returns inserted record in the response. So it will return inserted key to you.

Comment: In that case it will solve my problem. Now i just need to figure out how to avoid a "is not valid for the expected payload kind 'Resource'. " exception preventing me from getting the correct response. Thanks a lot Mak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i get an exception because .top() and .orderby is not supposed to be used together.

Where did you read that? In general `.top()` or `.Take()` should *ONLY* be used in conjunction *WITH* `.orderby()`, otherwise the record being retrieved is not guaranteed to be repeatable or predictable.

Probably the compounding issue here is mixing *query* and *fluent* expression syntax, which is valid, but you have to understand the order of precedence.
Your syntax is taking 1 record, then applying a sort order... you might find it easier to start with a *query* like this:

```
// build your query
var SecurityDefsQuery = from SD in nav.ICESecurityDefinition 
                        orderby SD.Entry_No descending 
                        select SD;
// Take the first item from the list, if it exists, will be a single record.
var SecurityDefs = SecurityDefsQuery.FirstOrDefault();
// Take an array of only the first record if it exists
var SecurityDefsDeferred = SecurityDefsQuery.Take(1);
```

This can be executed on a single line using brackets, but you can see how the query is the same in both cases, `SecurityDefs` in this case is a single `ICESecurityDefinition` typed record, where as `SecurityDefsDeferred` is an `IQueryable<ICESecurityDefinition>` that only has a single record.

If you only need the record itself, you this one liner:

```
var SecurityDefs = (from SD in nav.ICESecurityDefinition 
                    orderby SD.Entry_No descending 
                    select SD).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can execute the same query using *fluent* notation as well:

```
var SecurityDefs = nav.ICESecurityDefinition.OrderByDescending(sd => sd.Entry_No)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

In both cases, `.Take(1)` or *.top()* is being implemented through `.FirstOrDefault()`. You have indicated that speed is important, so use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.Single()` or `.SingleOrDefault()` because the single variants will actually request `.Take(2)` and will throw an exception if it returns 1 or no results.

> The *OrDefault* variants on both of these queries will not impact the performance of the query itself and should have negligble affect on your code, use the one that is appriate for your logic that uses the returned record and if you need to handle the case when there is no existing record.

If the record being returned has many columns, and you are only interested in the `Entry_No` column value, then perhaps you should simply query for that specific value itself:

#### *Query expression*:

```
var lastEntryNo = (from SD in nav.ICESecurityDefinition 
                   orderby SD.Entry_No descending 
                   select SD.Entry_No).FirstOrDefault();
```

#### *Fluent expression*:

```
var lastEntryNo = nav.ICESecurityDefinition.OrderByDescending(sd => sd.Entry_No)
                                           .Select(sd => sd.Entry_No)
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

If Speed is *paramount* then look at providing a specific custom endpoint on the service to either serve the record or do not process the 'Entry_No` in the client at all, make that the job of the code that receives data from the client and compute it at the time the entries are inserted.

Making the query perform faster is not the silver bullet you might be looking for though, Even if this is highly optimised, your current pattern means that `X` number of clients could all call the service to get the current value of `Entry_No`, meaning all of them would start incrementing from the same value.

If you *MUST* increment the `Entry_No` from the *client* then you should look at putting a custom endpoint on the service to simply return the *Next* `Entry_No` to use. This should be *optimistic* meaning that you don't care if the `Entry_No` actually gets used in the end, but you can implement the end point such that every call will increment the field in the database and return the next value.

> Its getting a bit beyond the scope of your initial post, but SQL Server now has support for [Sequences](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-sequence/) that formalise this type of logic from a database and schema point of view, using *Sequence* simplifies how we can manage these types of incrementations from the client, because we no longer rely on the outcome of data updates to be comitted to the table before the client can increment the next record. (which is what your `TOP`, `Order By` `Desc` solution is trying to do.